# Powershell - Matching text from array and string?

Tags: powershell

I have an array that simply pulls a list of numbers in one long column. I am trying to match it with some data in a string and if it matches, I am wanting it to state Down otherwise it will state Up in the output CSV.

Here is my code: `

```
IF($RESULTS -like $TEST)
        {$Output = "DOWN"
        }ELSE{
        $OUtput = "UP"
        }
```

`

$RESULTS is the array, and $TEST is the string.  If I do -match it works, but -match only pulls single digits so it gives false positives. For example, if there is a 3 in the list as well as 638 it will mark them both as down. None of the other switches seem to work like -eq, -like, etc.

What am I missing please?

Thanks much for any assistance!

EDIT:
Sample of Data in $TEST
2
3
5

Sample of Output of $RESULTS
5
628

Since 5 exists in both, my expected output would be DOWN and everything else would be UP.

Comment: I don't see how -like and -eq would be different without wildcards.  For match you would have to add word boundaries like `\b3\b`.

Comment: So it seems your variable `$TEST` is also an array of numbers? (not a string at all)

Comment: @Theo right side of -eq or -like gets converted from an array to a string, like `'2 3 5'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have *two* arrays of numbers, and you want to test if the input array contains at least one of the values in the test array.

You can use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object), which compares two arrays and indicates which elements are different and, with `-IncludeEqual`, also which ones are the same:

```
if (
  (Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $RESULTS $TEST).
    Where({ $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' }).
    Count -gt 0
) {
  $Output = "DOWN"
}
else {
  $Output = "UP"
}
```

---

As an aside:

You can use an `if` statement *as an expression*, which means you only need to specify `$Output` *once*:

```
$Output = 
  IF (<# conditional #>) {
    "DOWN"
  }
  ELSE {
    "UP"
  }
```

In [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can use `?:`, the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) for a more concise solution:

```
$Output = <# conditional #> ? 'DOWN' : 'UP'
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me on the right track!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Aramus.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by using "foreach". Hope this might be helpful

```
foreach ($result in $RESULTS){
    if ($result -like $Test){
        $OUTPUT = "Down"}
        else{
        $OUTPUT= "UP"}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your edited question you show that variable `$TEST` is also an array, so in that case you can do

```
$TEST    = 2,3,5
$RESULTS = 5,628
# compare both arrays for equal items
$Output = if ($TEST | Where-Object { $RESULTS -contains $_ }) {"DOWN"} else {"UP"}
$Output
```

In this case, $Output will be `DOWN` because both arrays have the number 5

If however variable `$TEST` contains a multiline string, then first create an array out of that like

```
$TEST = @'
2
3
5
'@
# convert the string to array by splitting at the newline
$TEST = $TEST -split '\r?\n' -ne ''
$RESULTS = 5,628
# compare both arrays for equal items
$Output = if ($TEST | Where-Object { $RESULTS -contains $_ }) {"DOWN"} else {"UP"}
$Output
```